# angular translate language to server

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I'm new to angular-translate, and was asking myself what is the best practice for keeping the language on the client in sync with the language when calling an API.

Would you use an extra parameter; a custom accept verb; something else for sending the client language?

And how can you get the actual selected language from angular-translate?

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on how you set the language in client. If you have user profiles stored on server, you could load user's preferred language in the API without passing language back and forth. You can also store language in cookie or use request header as you mentioned. Personally I think adding an extra parameter to API calls is cleanest and most transparent approach. $translate use is both getter and setter, so you can do following:

```
var currLang = $translate.use();
```